# Java multithreading not thread-safe using synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

A simple multithreading test with synchronization. I thought if it was "synchronized," other threads would wait. What am I missing?

```
public class MultithreadingCounter implements Runnable {

    static int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numThreads = 4;
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[numThreads];

        for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
            threads[i] = new Thread(new MultithreadingCounter(), i + "");

        for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
            threads[i].start();

        for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
            try {
                threads[i].join();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }           

    @Override
    public void run() {
        increment();
    }

    public synchronized void increment(){
            System.out.print(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + count + "\t");
            count++; // if I put this first or increment it directly in the print line, it works fine.
    }
}
```

I thought this would display something like:

```
0: 1    2: 0    1: 2    3: 3
```

But its actual output:

```
0: 0    2: 0    1: 0    3: 3
```

and other variations like this. It should display each increment (i.e. 0,1,2,3) not in order...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `synchronized` keyword is on an instance method. No two threads can execute this method *of one of your thread objects* at the same time. But, that is not what your code does. Each thread executes the method on its own instance. The synchronization does not do what you seem to intend. If it were a `static` method, it would.

Comment: Would making it `static` (in combination with `synchronized`) gate it sufficiently, or should he make the variable `volatile` as well?

Comment: (Correct) synchronization is enough. It already ensures that the increment has a happens-before relationship with subsequent reads, which is all that `volatile` would add.

Answer (score 1):

Your `increment` method should be `static`:

```
public static synchronized void increment() {
```

Right now, each object is synchronized on that individual instance, but since `count` is a static variable, you should be synchronizing on the `Class` object itself.

Comment: I was the one who made you get 3000 rep, yay :D

Answer (score 0):

when synchronized keyword is used before a method, it ensures that that method can be executed by only one thread at a time with respect to that object only. It does not ensure thread safety from other objects.